# How to do a specific action on the first iteration of a while loop in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make a script do a specific action on first loop iteration.

```
for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    echo "${file}"
done
```

I want this output:

```
First run: file1
file2
file3
file4
...
```

Comment: What do you mean? Just print `First run:` alone with the first file?

Comment: Yes, It just should do something differnet on the first run like print "first run:"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very common arrangement is to change a variable inside the loop.

```
noise='First run: '
for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    echo "$noise$file"
    noise=''
done
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an array with the files, then remove and keep the first element from this array, process it separately and then process the remaining elements of the array:

```
# create array with files
files=(/path/to/files/*)

# get the 1st element of the array
first=${files[0]}

# remove the 1st element of from array
files=("${files[@]:1}")

# process the 1st element
echo First run: "$first"

# process the remaining elements
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

I got my own solution

```
counter=1

for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    echo -e "$( if [ "${counter}" -eq "1" ]; then echo "First run: "; fi )${file}"

counter=$((counter +1))

done
```